# YML file dosn't work with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, yaml

I have a problem and  i really don't know how to solve it, and for me it doesn't make sens. Can anyone tell me where is the mistake because i can't see it. I am using spring-boot

Here I have the yml file:

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
 devices: 
  list: 
- id : TV1
  type : TV
  value : boolean
  name : TV_sufragerie
- id : TV2
  type : TV  
  value : boolean
  name : TV_dormitor
- id : Therme1
  type : Therme
  value : Double
  name : Therme-hol
- id : SmartBulb1
  type : SmartBulb
  value : SmartBulbValue
  name : SmartBulbDormitor
```

And this is how I try to take the data from the yml file:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("devices")
public class DeviceYml {

private List<DevicesList> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static class DevicesList {

    private String id;

    private  String type ;

    private List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "YAMLConfigDevice [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + ", value=" + value + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
public List<DevicesList> getDevices() {
    return list;
}

public void setDevices(List<DevicesList> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "devicesList=" + list + "";
}
}
```

I alsow have in the applicaton.properties this:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: can you format your yml properly, Its impossible to read it. Yml file will work only if its properly formatted. And also you don't have `spring.profiles.active` in yml. you have `spring.profiles` only

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure your yml is correctly formatted. Yml relies on space to properly get parsed.

Suppose the yml is correctly formatted, the problem lies on the getter and setter. Their names (call `getDevices` and `setDevices`) expect the yml to contain a key called `devices` but you have called it `devices.list`.